# code stuck when `global` is added

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I have weird problem-

I have this function

```
function doSomething(par1, par2)
global str;

// more code on remark..
// im using str here

end
```

this function located inside nested while

```
function mainFunction

global str; //im using str here
 while (i<500)
    while (j<500)

     doSomething(val1, val2);  // some variables
     j = j+1;
    end

  j=1
  i = i+1;
end
end
```

when I ran the code, it get stuck (even that the whole code inside that function is remarked and only the `global str` is left).
but when I remove the `global str` (empty function), only within the `doSomething` function, the code gets to the end and finishes correctly.

`str` is not complex database, its just regular string..

I don't quite know why it happens, or maybe im doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do you use a `global` function at all? It is much better practice to rather just pass `str` to `doSomething` as a parameter: `function doSomething(par1, par2, str)`. That said, where do you update `i` and `j`? And how do you know your programme is 'stuck'? Are you stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: `str` is parameter that both functions changes it. so pass it every iteration is quite waist I guess. I know my program is stuck because without the `global str` it finishes after 30 seconds, and with `global str` I stopped it after almost  three hours

Comment: It's not a waste, you really really should pass it in and pass it out every time. This is universally accepted good programming practice.  Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil and http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad on why what you are doing is wrong. It sounds like the runtime of `doSomething` depends on the value of `str`, use the MATLAB profiler to find out. Note you should change your `doSomething` function definition to something like `function str = doSomething(par1, par2, str)` and then call `str = doSomething(val1, val2, str)`.